# Banach fixed point theorem in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, fixed-point-theorems, closed-map

I have a question on Banach fixed-point theorem. It supposes we are in a closed set $C \subset \mathbb R^n$ with the image of $C$ by a function is included in $C : f(C)\subset C$ and we also suppose that $\exists \rho \in ]0, 1[ \text{ such that } \forall v, w \in C \lVert f(v) − f(w)\rVert \leq \rho \lVert v − w \rVert $.

Then $\exists! y \in C \text{ such that } f(y)=y.  $

Can $C$ be equal to $\mathbb R^n$ ? Does the result still holds ?

Comment: Is $\mathbb{R}^n$ closed?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh Yes but it don't know if the closed set required by the theorem is strictly included in $\mathbb R^n$

Comment: What does the theorem actually say about the issue of strict inclusion?

Comment: @John: Al that is required is that the domain  $C$ is a complete metric space ($\mathbb{R}^n$ is) and that, as you mentioned, $f(C)\subset C$. The reason for working in smaller sets (a compact box, or a closed ball) is that often, it is easier to show that s conservative function is indeed a contraction (the mean value theorem comes to mind).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $C$ can be any complete metric space, so a closed set of $\Bbb R^n$ works just as well as $\Bbb R^n$ itself.